# PHP Error Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect date value: when sending Date to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent the afternoon trying various solutions but despite numerous questions on 'SO', I have not been able to resolve this issue.

My PHP code is below where I want to INSERT dates into a mySQL table, the table only has 3 columns as per screenshot.
[image: mysql table]

The dates arrive in php already formatted as `2020-10-03`. My understanding was this would be sufficiently correct to send them directly to mySQL, however I have tried to convert them in different ways, but I still receive the following error:
[image: php error]

```
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/php/dbConnection.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//values passed from ajax
// $id         = $_POST['staffID'];
// $fromDate   = $_POST['startDate'];
// $endDate    = $_POST['endDate'];

//for testing > This Fails
$id         = '22';
$fromDate   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '10-06-2020')->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate    = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '12-06-2020')->format('Y-m-d');

//for testing > This Fails
//$id         = '22';
//$fromDate   = '2020-06-30';
//$endDate    = '2020-07-30';

$data       = array();      // array to pass back data

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO vacation (id, from_date, to_date)
                        VALUES ($id, $fromDate, $endDate)");
$stmt->execute();

$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Success!';


echo json_encode($data);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

appreciate any guidance on where I am going wrong and how I need to interpret this error message.

Cheers

Comment: *Unquoted* `2020-06-30` is an arithmetic operation, not a date - that yields `1984`. Bottom line: use prepared statements, and you won't have to worry about such problem, while making your code safer and more efficient.

Comment: See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for `mysqli` or [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo) for `PDO` (recommended) prepared statements.

Comment: @GMB thanks for the clarification I did wonder where 1987 was been generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prepared statement so you don't need to convert the date and also it's more secure because it's prevent SQL injection
so here is the changed code

```
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/php/dbConnection.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//values passed from ajax
// $id         = $_POST['staffID'];
// $fromDate   = $_POST['startDate'];
// $endDate    = $_POST['endDate'];

//for testing > This Fails
$id         = '22';
$fromDate   = '10-06-2020'
$endDate    = '12-06-2020'

//for testing > This Fails
//$id         = '22';
//$fromDate   = '2020-06-30';
//$endDate    = '2020-07-30';

$data       = array();      // array to pass back data

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO vacation (id, from_date, to_date)
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $id, $fromDate, $endDate);

$stmt->execute();

$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Success!';


echo json_encode($data);

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```